# Authenticating multiple profiles under the same account in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to set up an account profile system to allow parents to manage their child's profile in the same account. Think of it working similarly to Netflix's profile selection when you sign in. How can I authenticate the selected profile within Firestore's rules or is there an easier way to manage multiple profiles under a single user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a case where User Profile <> User Account. This gives you two main options:

- You can introduce your own profile system, with all relevant profiles tied to a single Firebase Authentication account.
- You can use separate Firebase Authentication account for each profile, in which case you'll need to introduce your own grouping mechanism for these accounts.

Given that you want to grant access permissions in Firestore security rules for each profile, the latter probably makes most sense. In this scenario I'd [use a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) in these accounts to tie them into the same group/family.